# Chrome incorrectly rendering symbols/special fonts?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, windows-10-v1703

For an example, check out this screenshot of https://material.io/icons/:

[image]

I've tried clearing my cache.  I tried in incognito (not an extension problem).  I have the latest version (Version 59.0.3071.115).

It works fine in IE and Edge.

Not sure what's going on. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Developer Tools to determine why the fonts file does not load.

1. Navigate to https://material.io/icons
2. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> to bring up Developer Tools
3. Select the Console tab
4. Refresh the website.

Any errors loading a part of the website will be shown here in red.

For more details, right-click on a filename that failed to load and click "Open in new tab"

Comment: Of course... It was uBlock Origin.  Apparently it was enabled in Incognito mode too.  Oops.